# cocos2d position sprite according to touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite looking like a pencil. I want to draw a line when user touches this sprite.
I am able to draw the line on touch location & move the sprite accordingly. The problem is that the line is not drawing from tip of the pencil which lies at left bottom of the sprite.

I don't want to move the left bottom edge of sprite under the touch point because then user will not be able to see the tip but instead shift the coordinates to draw to the tip itself.

I tried setAnchorPoints but that's not helping. Anyone tried this or has better ideas please do share. Thanks.

Comment: draw the line at an offset to the touch location

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the line at something like pencil.position.y - (pencil.sizeofthesprite.y / 2) and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this before but it doesn't seem to be working. I think this is because as user can touch any point on the sprite and touch location doesn't need to be the center of the sprite. Also since I am drawing lines with currentLocation and previousLocation points of UITouch, somehow I need to shift both of them left edge of the sprite.

Comment: Why don´t you try to draw the line using the position of the pencil sprite? This way you only use the touch for detecting whether the sprite has been touched or not, and then move the sprite accordingly while drawing the line using the sprite´s previous positions. Hope this helps!

Comment: sprite's position is the center of the sprite. But as I mentioned, the tip of pencil is at left bottom of the sprite (0,0). Moreover, if I draw it as position of the sprite, user won't be able to see it while drawing. Earlier I was drawing at position of touch point but that also has same problem as I mentioned above.